# Send files created in last minute with sftp one line?

Tags: find, cron, sftp

I would like to SFTP files with a .json only files created in the last minute.

For context: the machine I'm using has no internet connection, so I cannot install additional packages through yum, the linux machine is RedHat.

I have seen [find on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032188/how-to-find-file-accessed-created-just-few-minutes-ago/14032268) which would look like this for one minute -

```
find . -cmin -1
```

Ideally, I would like to pipe this through to the sftp command so I can send new files created in the last minute, every minute from a cron job.

How would I go about this?

And, all done in a one line command?

Comment: Note: `-cmin` deals with `ctime` which is "inode change time", not "creation time". It seems you may want `btime`. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/918303/693277). In general the kernel, the filesystem and tools may support `btime`. Or `ctime` may be as good (or even better) for what you want to do. Anyway my point is you're confusing the two.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for that info. btime is what I'm after as I want it on file creation.